# Unable to configure UDP on ingress-nginx-controller

Tags: kubernetes, udp, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I use Azure Kubernetes to host a couple of different services.

I'm trying to configure UDP load balancing over external IP.
I have created service with type LoadBalancer, UDP protocol and sessionAffinity. Also my deployment has configured HTTP RedinessProbe.

If UDP client reach my service from kubernetes network every thing works fine:
- client have sticky session to concrete pod in ready state.
- client re-balanced to another ready pod if already assigned pod was dead;
- client re-balanced after **sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds** is elapsed(i.e next packets may be routed to other ready pod).

Thinks go different if I try to connect to LoadBalancer externally(using external IP):
- client have sticky session to concrete pod in ready state.
- client doesn't get new ready pod if previous was dead. It connected to new pod only in case If client stop to send messages during **sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds** period of time.

So to solve it I tried to use ingress-nginx. I found useful article [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md)  about this kind of configuration.

But after I completed with udp-service configuration and adding UDP port I get following error:

> cannot create an external load balancer with mix protocols

Could You please point me how to do it properly in Kubernetes.

udp-services config map:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: udp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
  5684: "dev/dip-dc:5684"
```

ingress-nginx controller service YAML:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: ingress-nginx2
namespace: ingress-nginx
labels:
app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
externalTrafficPolicy: Local
type: LoadBalancer
selector:
app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
ports:
- name: http
port: 80
targetPort: http
- name: https
port: 443
targetPort: https
- name: upd
port: 5684
targetPort: udp
```

Answer (score 2):

A multi-protocol LB service is unfortunately not supported in many K8S providers.

Check out this [**tutorial**](https://medium.com/asl19-developers/build-your-own-cloud-agnostic-tcp-udp-loadbalancer-for-your-kubernetes-apps-3959335f4ec3) that shows you how to build your own UDP/TCP load balancer.

The summary of what you will need to do is:

1. Create a NodePort service for your application
2. Create a small server instance and run Nginx with LB config